# Bind ErrorProvider

Tags: c#, winforms, binding

Доброго времени суток, получил проблему, честно, гуглил - не помогло. Есть форма, все элементы (text, color в textbox-ах) связаны с некоторым классом `ViewModel` (наследует `INotifyPropertyChanged`) через `DataBindings`. В процессе ввода текста в `textbox` на каждое действие проверяется корректность введенных данных. Если текущее значение в textbox-е некорректно, то меняется цвет текста, отключается кнопка - все это работает. Но есть задача вывести подсказку, что не так. Кинул на форму `ErrorProvider` - у каждого textbox-a появилось новое свойство - `Error`. Его я тоже привязал к string-свойству `ViewModel`. При открытии этой формы получаю следующее:

[image: окно ошибки]

Как разрешить эту проблему?

Comment: Ну, судя по тексту ошибки, проблема в каком-то из биндингов. Покажите код, по Вашему описанию вряд ли кто-то сможет помочь

Comment: После моих действий в дизайн-редакторе у TextBox-а появилась такая строчка `this._textBox.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Error", this._bindingSource, "PasswordWarning", true, System.Windows.Forms.DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged, ""));` В общем-то на этом код заканчивается. Единственное, что приходит в голову - как будто свойство "Error" не строковое. Но как-то слабо в это верю - я вбивал жестко в свойство Error какой-нибудь текст - никаких ошибок.